# Crash on Canvas SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

i'm implementing a little app with new iOS framework SwiftUI. I'm using `@EnvironmentObject` to bind my data to view. All works, but the Canvas crash and not show nothing. Why?

```
struct CompetitionsListSwiftUIView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var competitionsViewModel: CompetitionsViewModel

    var body: some View {
        List(self.competitionsViewModel.competitions.identified(by: \.id)) { competition in
                CompetitionCellSwiftUIView(competition: competition)
            }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct CompetitionsListSwiftUIView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CompetitionsListSwiftUIView()
    }
}
#endif
```

The error message of the Canvas is this:

```
Error Domain=render service Code=12 "Rendering service was interrupted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Rendering service was interrupted}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try adding your environment object to the preview:

```
#if DEBUG
struct CompetitionsListSwiftUIView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CompetitionsListSwiftUIView()
          .environmentObject(CompetitionsViewModel())
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Saved my day. Compiler doesn't show any related error. Error reporting is not good in case of Previews

Comment: Xcode team should add more debug information for why the Preview Canvas crashed.

Comment: Got to love XCode's most descriptive error message of the year. Saved me hours of messing. Thank you

Comment: Thank you! Saved me from going crazy